# Save video file from Isolated Storage to Media Library

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Is it possible to save recorded video from isolated storage to media library to be accessible without application (for example for synchronization with PC)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes absolutely.  You either need to get access to the video library through manifest or get the user to save it to the video library through the file picker save dialog.

Comment: Could you please clarify how? Cuz now I have no programmatic access to video library.

Comment: You can use the File Picker API - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.filesavepicker.aspx and the user can save to videosLibrary.  Or you can specify access permissions to video Library in the AppxManifest and yourself programmatically save to it - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230259(v=vs.110).aspx#Capabilities